# iFrame not loading inside Flex popup

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, adobe, mxml

I'm trying to load pdf inside of iFrame which open in a pop-up window. Pop up is showing but but its not loading pdf. 
Here is my code -Main.mxml

```
 <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import com.google.code.flexiframe.IFrame;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

        protected function dgGrid_itemDoubleClick(event:Event):void {
            var win : Window = new Window();
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(win,this,true);
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(win);
        }
```

Now Window.mxml

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <mx:TitleWindow xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
            layout="vertical" width="742" height="452"
            title="PopUp Window" horizontalAlign="center"
            xmlns:flexiframe="http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/"
            xmlns:components="components.*"
            showCloseButton="true"
            close="closeWindow(event);" >

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.core.IFlexDisplayObject;
        import mx.events.CloseEvent;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

        private function closeWindow(e:CloseEvent):void {
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(e.target as IFlexDisplayObject);
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<flexiframe:IFrame id="iframe" source="C:\\test.pdf" 
      backgroundColor="blue" width="100%" height="100%" visible="true"/>
```

Can you please suggest whats wrong with it?

Comment: You could use [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html) instead of flex-iframe.

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks for your reply again! I think StagewebView is used for AIR but I want to use in web project. Any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your tags too quickly.  Also worth noting this appears to be Flex 3.

Comment: Try `source="file://c:\\test.pdf"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your **index.template.html** file and put the following parameter in your SWF:

```
params.wmode= "opaque";
```

Keep in mind that though this setting may fix many of the issues with the IFrame, it does however cause performance issues on certain flash versions and browsers. Use IFrames at your own risk.